# Start activity for result ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, startactivityforresult

I am a beginner in Ionic and I am developing an app which requires a user to sign in before he places an order.
Right now, if the user tries to place an order and he is not signed in, I need a logic where I can redirect him to the login page and on success, I can redirect him back to the order page. This would have been possible in android using start activity for the result. But how can I achieve this in Ionic?
I have a solution of opening the login page using modal and dismissing it on success but I do not want to implement that solution as of now.

Comment: you should just push(LoginPage) and then dismiss it on successful auth.

Comment: This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example whcih open modal via login. **Path and IonicPage should be adjusted before using the below code**. Maybe you can get a point from the code.

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth.provider'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public authService:AuthProvider) {

  }

  goToOrder(){
    this.authService.openModalViaLogin('OrderPage', {}, ()=>{})
  }
}
```

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth.provider';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public authService:AuthProvider, public viewCtrl:ViewController) {
  }

  login(){
    this.authService.isAuthenticated = true;
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss()
  }

  close(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss()
  }

}
```

**auth.provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {
  public isAuthenticated:boolean = false;

  constructor(public modalCtrl:ModalController) {
    console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
  }

  public openModalViaLogin(modalPage:string, params:any, callbackOnDidDismissed:Function){
    if(this.isAuthenticated){
      let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(modalPage,params)
      modal.onDidDismiss(()=>{
        callbackOnDidDismissed()
      })
      modal.present()
    }else{
      let loginModal = this.modalCtrl.create('LoginPage')
      loginModal.onDidDismiss(()=>{
        if(this.isAuthenticated){
          let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(modalPage,params)
          modal.onDidDismiss(()=>{
            callbackOnDidDismissed()
          })
          modal.present()
        }else{
          console.log("failed to authenticate")
        }
      })
      loginModal.present()
    }
  }
}
```

p.s. I think there is a more flexible way to achieve it by `nav` but that can be quite confusing with this short anwser.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will try the same logic with the pushing the login page and dismiss it on success than to try it with Modal since I had mentioned in my question that I do not wish to use a modal.

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed it. But if you need similar logic with other pages, it is better to modularize this process as **provider** regardless of `modal or push`